# How to do count on 2 (partial) values from 1 column in 1 table with 1 SQL query

Tags: sql

Let's say I have this 1 table called Reviews. There is a column Text in this table which holds full reviews as a text string.
From this I would like to do a count for all reviews having the word 'love' as part of the Text column and from the same SQL query also do a count for all reviews having the word 'hate' as part of the Text column.

Comment: Make it easy to assist you: [mcve].

Answer (score 1):

Something like a conditional sum perhaps:

```
select 
    Sum(case when review like '%love%' then 1 else 0 end) loveCount,
    sum(case when review like '%hate%' then 1 else 0 end) hateCount
from reviews
```